# Filtering code elements when analyzing source code

Tags: code-analysis, static-analysis

Currently I am making a survey about source code analysis and the thing that puzzles me greatly is what is it that project managers and developers would like to filter when analyzing source code (especially when applying OOP metrics - e.g. skpping insignificant methods and classes during analysis or filtering context-based elements according to the type of project). If you have any suggestions based on yout experience with code analysis I will greatly appreciate if you can share some ideas about filtering of elements.
   Thanks, Martin

Answer (score 1):

You might want to filter out third-party code and libraries since that's non of your concern.

You might also want to filter out code that is not of interest for a particular form of analysis. This might be useful if you have a huge code base and do not want to re-run the analysis on all of it, some of which has not been modified in decades.

Comment: I strongly disagree that third-party code which you include in a shipping product is none of your concern, but I agree that project managers and developers all too frequently would like to filter it out.